# How to compare rows in a single column?

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison, pivot, rows

I have data like the below in an Oracle database

```
Name   Session     CATEGORY   HT     WT     BMI
John   SESSION 1   OW         1.5    64.6   28.71
John   SESSION 3   OW         1.5    64.6   28.71
Eric   SESSION 1   OW         1.48   55.7   25.43
Eric   SESSION 3   OW         1.52   55.4   23.98
```

I have converted the above data like this using pivot

```
Name  session_1_Category  Session_1_height  session_1_weight  session_1_BMI  session_3_Category  Session_3_height  session_3_weight  session_3_BMI
John  OW                  1.5               64.6              28.71          OW                  1.5               64.6              28.71
Eric  OW                  1.48              55.7              25.43          OW                  1.52              55.4              23.98
```

I want to compare session 1 height with session 3 height, and session 1 weight with session 3 weight.

For e.g.

```
if SESSION_1_HEIGHT =SESSION_3_HEIGHT then height_status=true else height_status=false 
if SESSION_1_WEIGHT =SESSION_3_WEIGHT then weight_status=true else weight_status=false
if SESSION_1_BMI =SESSION_3_BMI then bmi_status=true else bmi_status=false
```

Please look here at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f7fc9/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Table that you sampled at SqlFiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( Name, "Session", CATEGORY, HT, WT, BMI ) AS
SELECT 'John', 'SESSION 1', 'OW', 1.5,  64.6, 28.71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'SESSION 3', 'OW', 1.52, 63.2, 27.35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eric', 'SESSION 1', 'OW', 1.48, 55.7, 25.43 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eric', 'SESSION 3', 'OW', 1.52, 55.4, 23.98 FROM DUAL;
```

This should give the result you wanted:

```
SELECT T.*, CASE WHEN T.SESSION_1_HEIGHT = T.SESSION_3_HEIGHT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HeightEquals, CASE WHEN T.SESSION_1_WEIGHT = T.SESSION_3_WEIGHT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WeightEquals, CASE WHEN T.SESSION_1_BMI = T.SESSION_3_BMI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BmiEquals FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table_name
  PIVOT(
    MAX( HT ) AS height,
    MAX( WT ) AS weight,
    MAX( BMI ) AS BMI
    FOR "Session" IN (
      'SESSION 1' AS Session_1,
      'SESSION 3' AS Session_3
    )
  )
) T;
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with `Oracle` and `PIVOT`, but you can use `CASE` to do your comparisons.

I had to remove the `SELECT *` and replace it with the list of fields, I'm not sure why that was necessary sorry.

```
SELECT name, category, 
session_1_height, session_1_weight, session_1_bmi,
session_3_height, session_3_weight, session_3_bmi,
CASE WHEN session_1_height = session_3_height THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS height_status,
CASE WHEN session_1_weight = session_3_weight THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS weight_status,
CASE WHEN session_1_bmi = session_3_bmi THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS bmi_status
FROM   table_name
PIVOT(
    MAX( HT ) AS height,
    MAX( WT ) AS weight,
    MAX( BMI ) AS BMI
    FOR "Session" IN (
        'SESSION 1' AS Session_1,
        'SESSION 3' AS Session_3
    )
);
```